# Touch ID API with PIN fallback

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, keychain, touch-id

We are working on an application where we use Touch ID to read a secret from the keychain.

We have found that when you read from the keychain *immediately* after a previous read, the read will not return the string value the second time if a PIN code is used to read the secret the first time. If the user uses their fingerprint the first time, the Touch ID dialog will be presented the second time and another read is successful.

Here is an example application: https://github.com/cnandreu/KeychainTouchIdError

Below are some scenarios using KeychainTouchIdError the demo application. These must be executed on a real device running iOS 8 with a touch id sensor. All the scenarios work as expected when using the simulator since the Touch ID dialog is never presented.

**Scenario 1 (working)**

- Store value in keychain protected by
  kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly.
- Read from keychain,
  use fingerprint to unlock.
- No delay.
- Read from keychain, use
  fingerprint or PIN to unlock.

**Scenario 2 (broken on devices):**

- Store value in keychain protected by kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly.
- Read from keychain, use PIN to unlock.
- No delay.
- Read from keychain. When using a device the touch ID dialog is not presented and a null string is returned from the keychain. However, when using the simulator, the value stored in the keychain is correctly retrieved.

**Scenario 3 (working):**

- Store value in keychain protected by kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly.
- Read from keychain, use PIN to unlock.
- Wait 500ms.
- Read from keychain. The user is presented a dialog and can read the secret again after using their fingerprint or PIN.

**Buttons available in demo application**

Save - Write a secret to the keychain protected by kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly.

Read - Reads a secret from the keychain.

Remove - Remove the secret from the keychain.

Quick - Used to perform scenario 1 and 2.

Quick with Delay - Used to perform scenario 3.

**Comments**

Our best guess is that the animation for the PIN unlock, which is a swipe down and lasts for about 250ms, is interfering with the second read. There is no animation when unlocking with a fingerprint. This is just a guess though.

Any ideas as to why we are running into a problem with Scenario 2? Is there anything that needs to be done to wait for the keychain to be ‘readable’ again?